# no logro insertar los datos en mi base de datos

Tags: php

buenas tardes tengo dos formularios y uno que es sencillo si me registra los datos y el otro que trae mas datos no me registra y ya los compare y están iguales la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal pero cuando consulto si el dato existe si me funciona pero si quiero registrar no

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
<?php
    include ('../../conection/conectar.php');

  //PARA REGISTRAR
  if(isset($_POST['guardar']))
  {
    $dd = $_POST['dd'];
    $orden = $_POST['orden'];
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $primer_nombre = $_POST['primer_nombre'];
    $segundo_nombre = $_POST['segundo_nombre'];
    $primer_apellido = $_POST['primer_apellido'];
    $segundo_apellido = $_POST['segundo_apellido'];
    $razon = $_POST['razon'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $ddrr = $_POST['ddrr'];
    $tele = $_POST['tele'];
    $nit = $_POST['nit'];
    $zona = $_POST['zona'];
    $cond = $_POST['cond'];        
    $dane = $_POST['dane'];
    $barrio = $_POST['barrios'];
    $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];             

  //PARA VERIFICAR SI EL REGISTRO EXISTE
  if($verificar_cliente = mysqli_query($conexion," SELECT * FROM clientes_nv WHERE cliente = '$cliente'")); 
  if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_cliente) > 0){
    echo "<h4>EL CLIENTE YA ESTA REGISTRO</h4>";
    exit;
  }      
   //INSERTAR
   $insertar= "INSERT INTO clientes_nv (dd,orden,cliente,primer_nombre,segundo_nombre,primer_apellido,segundo_apellido,razon,ddrr,tele,nit,zona,email,cond,dane,barrios,ciudad,tipo) VALUES ('$dd','$orden','$cliente','$primer_nombre','$segundo_nombre','$primer_apellido','$segundo_apellido','$razon','$email,'$ddrr','$tele','$nit','$zona','$cond','$dane','$barrio','$ciudad','$tipo')";
   $resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
   if(!$resultado){
    echo "<h4>ERROR AL REGISTRARSE</h4>";     
   }else{
    echo "<h4>LOS DATOS SE INSERTARON CORRECTAMENTE</h4>";
  } 
  }
//////////////////////////////este es mi formulario

<form action="index.php" method="POST" class="formulario-1">
        <center>
            <h1 class="formulario_titulo">REGISTROS CLIENTES NUEVOS</h1>

       <label class="label-48">Dia</label>
      <select name="dd" class="input-33">
        <option>Dia de facturacion</option>
        <option>LUNES</option>
        <option>MARTES</option>
        <option>MIERCOLES</option>
        <option>JUEVES</option>
        <option>VIERNES</option>
        <option>SABADO</option>
        <option>DOMINGO</option>
      </select>
            <label class="label-48">Codigo cliente </label>
            <input type="text" name="cliente" class="input-48"><br><br>
            <label class="label-48">Primer Nombre </label>
            <input type="text" name="primer_nombre" class="input-48">
            <label class="label-48">Segundo Nombre </label>
            <input type="text" name="segundo_nombre" class="input-48"><br><br>
            <label class="label-48">Primer Apellido </label>
            <input type="text" name="primer_apellido" class="input-48">
            <label class="label-48">Segundo Apellido </label>
            <input type="text" name="segundo_apellido" class="input-48"><br><br>
            <label class="labe-33">Nit </label>
            <input type="text" name="nit" class="input-33">
            <label class="labe-33">Razon Social </label>
            <input type="text" name="razon" class="input-33">
            <label class="labe-33">Correo </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="input-33"><br><br>
            <label class="labe-33">Telefono </label>
            <input type="text" name="tele" class="input-33">
            <label class="labe-33">Direccion </label>
            <input type="text" name="ddrr" class="input-33">            
        <label class="labe-33">Barrios </label>
        <select name="barrios" class="input-33">
              <option></option>
              <option>ARGELIA</option>
              <option>ALMENAR</option>
              <option>ANTONIO NARIÑO</option>
              <option>ALCALA</option>
              <option>BOITA</option>
              <option>BRITALIA</option>
              <option>BOSA CENTRO</option>
              <option>BOSA CARBONEL</option>
              <option>BOSA SANJOSE</option>
              <option>BOSA BRASIL</option>
              <option>CASA BLANCA</option>
              <option>CAZUCA</option>
              <option>COMPARTR</option>
              <option>CIUDAD LATINA</option>
              <option>DANUVIO</option>
              <option>DINDALITO</option>
              <option>DUCALES</option>
              <option>GALAN</option>
              <option>20 DE JULIO</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label class="labe-33" class="input-33">Ciudades</label> 
            <select name="ciudad" class="input-33">
               <option></option>
               <option value="1">BOGOTA</option>
               <option value="2">SOACHA</option>
               <option value="3">SIBATE</option>
            </select>
            <label class="labe-33">Zona </label>
            <input type="text" name="zona" class="input-33">
            <label class="labe-33">Tipologia</label>
            <select name="tipo" class="input-33">
              <option ></option>
              <option value="201">TIENDAS</option>
              <option value="202">PANADERIAS Y PASTELERIAS</option>
              <option value="203">CIGARREEIAS</option>
              <option value="204">DROGUERIAS</option>
              <option value="205">MINIMERCADOS</option>
              <option value="206">MISCELANEOS</option>
              <option value="207">CARNES-QUESOS Y HUEVOS</option>
              <option value="208">GRANEROS</option>
              <option value="209">MAYORISTAS</option>
              <option value="210">OTROS</option>
              <option value="220">CAFETERIAS</option>
              <option value="221">HELADERIAS</option>
              <option value="222">INSTITUCIONES ACADEMICAS</option>
              <option value="223">RESTAURANTES INDEPENDIENTES</option>
              <option value="224">NEGOCIOS COMIDAS RAPIDAS</option>
              <option value="225">BARES-BILLARES</option>
              <option value="226">KIOSKOS</option>
              <option value="227">GIMNASIOS & SPA</option>
              <option value="229">DE TEMPORADA</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <label class="labe-33">Dane </label>
            <input type="text" name="dane" class="input-33">
            <label class="labe-33">Orden </label>
            <input type="text" name="orden" class="input-33">
            <label class="labe-33">Condicion </label>
            <input type="text" name="cond" class="input-33"><br>
           <br> 
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Registrar" class="formulario_submit">
            <input type="submit" name="consultar" value="consultar" class="formulario_submit">

    </form>
  </center>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SO. Imprime el error, para ver a qué se debe el fallo, modificando el mensaje de error que ya tienes de este modo: `echo "<h4>ERROR AL REGISTRARSE</h4>".mysqli_error($conexion);` Coméntanos lo que sale por pantalla.

Comment: me aparece este error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '','','','','','','','','','')' at line 1

Comment: Imprime tu sentencia de inserción a ver qué es lo que hay en ella: `echo $insertar;` y nos cuentas. Parece que no está capturando ningún valor pasado en el POST. ¿Tu archivo se llama `index.php`?

Comment: echo INSERT INTO clientes_nv (dd,orden,cliente,primer_nombre,segundo_nombre,primer_apellido,segundo_apellido,razon,ddrr,tele,nit,zona,email,cond,dane,barrios,ciudad,tipo) VALUES ('Dia de facturacion','','555','','','','','',','','','','','','','','','');  si señor  mi archivo se llama index.php

Comment: Sólo te está tomando el 1er valor y el tercero del POST, los otros no... ¿Esos campos tienen datos en el `form` al momento de enviarlo?

Comment: gracias A-cedano por brindarme tu ayuda buena noche

Comment: Me alegro. Finalmente quiero señalar que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Cuando puedas infórmate sobre ese riesgo y sobre la forma de evitarlo mediante el uso de consultas preparadas.

Comment: ok si señor muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Intenta insertar los datos concatenando las variables y no insertándolas dentro del mismo texto.

```
$insertar= "
  INSERT INTO clientes_nv (
    dd, orden, cliente, primer_nombre, 
    segundo_nombre, primer_apellido,
    segundo_apellido, razon, ddrr, tele, nit,
    zona, email, cond, dane, barrios, ciudad, tipo
  ) VALUES ( 
    '".$dd."', '".$orden."', '".$cliente."', '".$primer_nombre."', 
    '".$segundo_nombre."', '".$primer_apellido."', '".$segundo_apellido."', 
    '".$razon."', '".$email."', '".$ddrr."', '".$tele."', '".$nit."', 
    '".$zona."', '".$cond."', '".$dane."', '".$barrio."', '".$ciudad."', '".$tipo."'
  )
";
```

Comment: mas allá de que la respuesta sea útil para resolver el problema, es una grave problema de seguridad pasar los valores dinámicos que llegan directo a la consulta SQL

Comment: El problema no es la instrucción SQL. Concatenar del modo que lo está haciendo es válido y es correcto (lo puedes probar con variables cualesquiera). **El problema era que estaba dejando datos vacíos en el formulario al momento de enviarlo como demuestra [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228840/no-logro-insertar-los-datos-en-mi-base-de-datos#comment424986_228840)**. Para no caer en suposiciones aportando respuestas que en vez de ayudar lo que hacen es confundir, conviene leer los comentarios para saber cómo se ha ido desarrollando la solución del problema.

Answer (score -1):

Para poder ingresar valores de variables `string` dentro de una consulta al que se le debe indicar en el `INSERT` que el tipo de datos es `varchar` tenes que hacerlo utilizando la siguiente sintaxis

```
$insertar= "INSERT INTO clientes_nv (dd,orden,cliente,primer_nombre,segundo_nombre,primer_apellido,segundo_apellido,razon,ddrr,tele,nit,zona,email,cond,dane,barrios,ciudad,tipo) VALUES ('{$dd}','{$orden}','{$cliente}','{$primer_nombre}','{$segundo_nombre}','{$primer_apellido}','{$segundo_apellido}','{$razon}','{$email}','{$ddrr}','{$tele}','{$nit}','{$zona}','{$cond}','{$dane}','{$barrio}','{$ciudad}','{$tipo}')";
```

**Esto no es una buena practica ya que permite SQL injection**

Comment: No necesariamente, la consulta funcionaría también como la tiene actualmente, dado que la variable está englobada por dos comillas dobles.

Comment: @A.Cedano No es correcto su afirmación, ya que esta "envolviendo" el nomber de las variables con comillas simples, es por esto que MySQL le envia el error que le muestra

Comment: ya no entendí tu respuesta, lo soluciona, es bueno o no es bueno?

Comment: Por favor no confundas las cosas. Lee los comentarios, le pedí un `echo`de la consulta y los datos que vienen el POST se muestran correctamente. Puedes hacer una prueba con una variable cualquier y verás que la cadena se crea correctamente.

Comment: si ..señor gracias muy amable

Comment: Aquí tienes una prueba simple de que sí funciona: `$dd="dato1";
   $orden="dato2";
   $cliente="dato3";
   $insertar= "INSERT INTO clientes_nv (dd,orden,cliente,primer_nombre) VALUES ('$dd','$orden','$cliente')";
   echo $insertar;` la salida sería: **`INSERT INTO clientes_nv (dd,orden,cliente,primer_nombre) VALUES ('dato1','dato2','dato3')`** otra cosa muy distinta es que los valores numéricos no necesitan las comillas simples.

Comment: gracias Ale fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta lo tendré en cuenta ya solucione el inconveniente  gracias y buena noche